# Updating the php version of the chef php cookbook

Tags: php, ubuntu, chef-infra, vagrant

I am new to chef and trying to configure the php cookbook to install php 5.4.8 instead of the default php  5.3.10 on Ubuntu.

I've tried adding this setting in the attributes/default.rb file of my custom cookbook:

`default['php']['version'] = '5.4.8'`

but the installed version is still 5.3.10

`php -v`

`PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 19:00:43) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies`

How do I override the default setting for php version?

**Edit:**
Vagrant repo with php 5.4 based on the answer https://github.com/AlexDisler/php54-chef-env

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am new to this as well, and I did the same exact thing. I believe you need to add a package that points to the version of php you want.

Here is a recipe that you can check out.
https://github.com/homemade/chef-dotdeb

You want to add this at the top of of your run_list before you call the php recipe

ex.

If you're using vagrant (If you are not, you better go download it, it will make your life fun again) http://www.vagrantup.com

```
chef.add_recipe("dotdeb")
chef.add_recipe("dotdeb::php54")
chef.add_recipe("apache2")
chef.add_recipe("apache2::mod_php5")
chef.add_recipe("apache2::mod_rewrite")
chef.add_recipe("php")
```

I hope this helps you out.

EDIT:
I got to test this out, and it works. Goodluck!